# How to launch an application from the browser using PHP?

Tags: php, linux, shell, browser, exe

I have installed .exe file using wine in my linux machine. Using shell_exec I could launch the exe file via command prompt using php. When I try to run php program from the browser am getting a blank page. How to launch the executables from the browser using php?

And also, using ip address I should be able to launch in other system browser which is installed in one system.

php code:

```
<?php

shell_exec("cd / ; wine /home/quads/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/MathType/MathType.exe");
?>
```

If I run this through command prompt it could launch an application but via browser it 

doesn't work.It it works via browser then I can access that application from other system using

`myipaddress/phpprogram`

Comment: Do you want to run the .exe on the server or the client?

Comment: On the server.  So that I can view it on other system  too

Comment: You are probably going to have to show us your code, or we could only guess what could be wrong.

Comment: Why would you expect running an exe on the server to cause the PHP program that triggers it to output anything in particular?

Comment: Because,I need to launch the application from other system which is installed only in my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work only in Internet Explorer and ActiveX control should be enabled in the browser

code:

```
function openapp(){
var obj=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
obj.Run("file_exe_path",1,true);
}

<input type="button" onclick="openapp();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php

shell_exec("wine MathType");
?>
```

Comment: Its working through command prompt but not working through browser